# Date casting with parameter in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I have this code.

```
 Query q = session.createQuery("FROM SugarLevels WHERE identification = :identification AND date_submitted BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate ORDER BY date_submitted ASC");
        q.setParameter("identification", identification.toUpperCase());
        q.setParameter("startDate", startDate);
        q.setParameter("endDate", endDate);
```

However there will be an error ERROR: operator does not exist: date >= character varying
I tried doing

```
 Cast(:startDate as DATE)
```

but still an error. Anyone knows how to cast a parameter to date?

Comment: Found it. BETWEEN to_date(:startDate,'YYYY-MM-DD') AND to_date(:endDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD').

Answer (score 1):

```
Query q = session.createQuery("FROM SugarLevels WHERE identification = ? AND date_submitted BETWEEN ? AND ? ORDER BY date_submitted ASC");
q.setParameter(identification.toUpperCase());
q.setParameter(startDate);
q.setParameter(endDate);
```

May be you can using above code instead.